# Windows SCSI ReadCapacity16 in D

Tags: windows, winapi, d, scsi, deviceiocontrol

I'm attempting to send a scsi ReadCapacity16 (0x9E) to a volume on Windows using D. The CDBs are to spec and my ReadCapacity16 works on Linux and scsi Inquiries work on Windows. Only the not-inquiry calls on Windows fail to work with an "incorrect function" from the windows kernel.

Since only inquiries work, is there a trick to sending not-inquiries through the Windows kernel? Any tips on getting this to work? I've researched a couple weeks and haven't solved this.

This is an example of the CDB:

> \\.\physicaldrive0
>   CDB buffer contents:
>   9e 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00
>   sgio.exceptions.IoctlFailException@sgio\exceptions.d(13): ioctl error code is 1. Incorrect function.

Here is where the CDB is copied to a buffer for the DeviceIoControl call, and this is the same code path which successfully sends the Inquiry commands (but fails for readcap). [Code in github](https://github.com/ljdelight/sgio.d/blob/master/sgio/SCSIDevice.d#L82) pasted below:

```
void sgio_execute(ubyte[] cdb_buf, ubyte[] dataout_buf, ubyte[] datain_buf, ubyte[] sense_buf)
   version (Windows)
   {
      const uint SENSE_LENGTH = 196;
      ubyte[512] iobuffer = 0;
      DWORD amountTransferred = -1;
      SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT scsiPassThrough = {0};
      scsiPassThrough.Cdb[] = 0;
      uint size = cast(uint)((cdb_buf.length <= scsiPassThrough.Cdb.length ?
                        cdb_buf.length : scsiPassThrough.Cdb.length));

      scsiPassThrough.Cdb[0..size] = cdb_buf[0..size];
      scsiPassThrough.Length             = SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT.sizeof;
      scsiPassThrough.ScsiStatus         = 0x00;
      scsiPassThrough.TimeOutValue       = 0x40;
      scsiPassThrough.CdbLength          = cast(ubyte)(size);
      scsiPassThrough.SenseInfoOffset    = SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT.sizeof;
      scsiPassThrough.SenseInfoLength    = SENSE_LENGTH;
      scsiPassThrough.DataIn             = SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN;
      scsiPassThrough.DataBuffer         = datain_buf.ptr;
      scsiPassThrough.DataTransferLength = bigEndianToNative!ushort(cast(ubyte[2]) cdb_buf[3..5]);

      int status = DeviceIoControl( m_device,
                                    IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT,
                                    &scsiPassThrough,
                                    iobuffer.length, //scsiPassThrough.sizeof,
                                    &iobuffer,
                                    iobuffer.length,
                                    &amountTransferred,
                                    null);
      if (status == 0)
      {
         int errorCode = GetLastError();
         // build error message ...
         throw new IoctlFailException(exceptionMessage);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried READ CAPACITY(10), just to make sure that works?  Also, is this indexing for the allocation length correct: `cast(ubyte[2]) cdb_buf[3..5]`?  The alen starts in the 10th byte (0 relative).

Comment: Is  `datain_buf` properly device aligned?

Comment: @gubblebozer: All of ReadCapacity10/12/16 do not work. I'll dump the spt struct and check the offset of the DataTransferLength but I expect it's correct since [1] and [2] match. 

Ross: I think it's aligned, I allocate 32 bytes for datain of ReadCap16 and inquiries use the same code path. Is there a way to capture what the device receives?

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565346(v=vs.85).aspx
[2] https://github.com/ljdelight/sgio.d/blob/master/sgio/SCSIDevice.d#L21

Comment: Okay, so I think my problem is that I'm writing the int a little endian but the scsi spec requires big endian in those buffers. I'll hack and update if I get this working

Comment: I was hunting for any reason to get the code working and the BE vs LE was a witch hunt. The problem was exactly as @RossRidge mentioned: datain_buf wasn't aligned for the device (I didn't realize the requirement there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Windows SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT structure documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565346(v=vs.85).aspx) very closely I noticed this:

> DataTransferLength: Indicates the size in bytes of the data buffer.
>   Many devices transfer chunks of data of predefined length. The value
>   in DataTransferLength ***must be an integral multiple of this predefined,
>   minimum length*** that is specified by the device. If an underrun occurs,
>   the miniport driver must update this member to the number of bytes
>   actually transferred.

I changed the code to use 512 bytes for DataTransferLength, by increasing the size of datain_buffer, and the code now works just fine.